# Why Joda DateTime gives different result than Java Date?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I tested [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) DateTime against `java.util.Date` with UTC timezone, and I encountered an interesting case:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dt = "2011-06-11T12:00:00Z";
        String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'";

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        Date d = df.parse(dt);
        DateTime joda = new DateTime(dt);

        // Output Sat Jun 11 05:00:00 PDT 2011
        System.out.println(joda.toDate());

        // Output Fri Jun 10 17:00:00 PDT 2011
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

I wonder is this a bug to either one or I missed something important here?

Comment: You are setting UTC timezone only to "d" variable which is java.util.Date. Set the timezone also for Joda DateTime "joda" variable.

Comment: By the way, your DateTime is getting a default time zone. If you want UTC/GMT (or any specific time zone), pass a [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object. For UTC/GMT, there is a [predefined constant "UTC"](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#UTC). Like this: `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2011-06-11T12:00:00Z", DateTimeZone.UTC );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Edit: a clearer and more correct answer)

<strike>I believe it is because JODA and Java Date Format is treating "12" in 12-hour presentation differently.  One of them treat it as midnight, while the other treat it as noon.</strike>

Change your input to `2011-06-11T01:00:00Z` will prove my hypothesis.

It is because, you are creating JODA time using the constructor of DateTime, which in turns parse your String using ISO format, for which use 24-hour format : [Default format used by JODA](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser%28%29), while the DateFormat you used to construct your Java Date is using `hh` for hour field, which means 12-hour format.  Therefore they interpret "12" differently: 12-hour format treat it as mid-night, while 24-hour treat it as noon.

Easiest change is to change the format to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` which use 24-hour presentation, then both of them works fine.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks a lot, I didn't know that changing to uppercase does mean something.

Comment: @Chan FYR: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html  &  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html .